How to get WooCommerce shop page to show full width
I'm struggling to get my WooCommerce shop page full size (or at least wider than default). I've tried all sorts of CSS codes from other posts, but they either also change my other pages, or don't do anything at all.
I'm using Fascinate child theme, and WooCommerce width settings are not available in the customizer.
This is my shop page: https://www.blankamorikawa.art/shop/
Ideally, I'd like it as wide as my portfolio pages - i.e.: https://www.blankamorikawa.art/portfolio/2024-2/.
Any advice on how to achieve this?

This can be done using CSS. You have to inspect the elements within the page in order to target the right class/id.
You do so by: Right click anywhere on a page -> Select inspect/inspect element -> Elements panel will open, showing the HTML and CSS of the page.
Checking you specific portfolio page, you can see that the element with class body.no-sidebar .alignfull containing your portfolio items has a width set to 90vw.
Portofolio page


In your shop page check class .fb-container. This has a max-width set to max-width: 1170px;. This limits your shop page to being maximum 1170px in width. So in order to have full width, you would have to set the max-width to e.g. 100% for class .fb-container.
Shop page


In order to only target the shop page, you can target the specific <body> class woocommerce-shop.

So your CSS code could look like this:
.woocommerce-shop .fb-container {
   max-width: 100% !important;
}


This worked, thank you so much! I'm a CSS novice, so I didn't know how to specify the shop only.

Hi Richard, can you also advice how will the CSS code look like for a category page - i.e.:  https://www.blankamorikawa.art/product-category/canvas-paintings/? I thought I would replicate the same, just edit the body class, but I'm not sure how to do so. TIA!

Got it, I think - .woocommerce-js.hfeed :)

@BlankaMorikawa Look for at an id or class which distinguish the page from other woocommerce templates. In this case hfeed is unique to your category page. But on your category page, you have to target the class .col-lg-8 because this is what contains the grid elements. This has max-width set to 66.666667% and flex: 66.666667%. So use this: .hfeed .col-lg-8 { max-width: 100% !important; flex: 0 0 100% !important; }

Remove or increase the max width value
.fb-container {
  max-width: 1170px;
}

This is how it looks after the modification.

this is how it was before

If you want to be specific to the page, point to the class

Amazing, thanks so much!!!
